# Undefined control sequence \subsetneq

Tags: errors, symbols

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,titlepage,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[cm-default,no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xgreek}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{DejaVu Sans}
\parindent=0in

\begin{document}

$A \subseteq B$ \\
\\
$C \subsetneq D$

\end{document}
```

the first equation appears right the second as CD with no symbol in between.

I also get the following error message from **xelatex**:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.16 $C \subsetneq
D$
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 14--17
[]
[1
] (./basic.aux) )
```

if I add \usepackage{amssymb} I get the following error message

```
! LaTeX Error: Command `\Finv' already defined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.231 ...ol{\Finv} {\mathord}{AMSb}{"60}
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
! LaTeX Error: Command `\Game' already defined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.232 ...ol{\Game} {\mathord}{AMSb}{"61}
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
! LaTeX Error: Command `\beth' already defined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.237 ...ol{\beth} {\mathord}{AMSb}{"69}
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
! LaTeX Error: Command `\gimel' already defined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.238 ...ol{\gimel} {\mathord}{AMSb}{"6A}
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
! LaTeX Error: Command `\daleth' already defined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.239 ...ol{\daleth} {\mathord}{AMSb}{"6B}
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/xgreek/xgreek.sty
File: xgreek.sty 2008/06/22 v2.0 Package `xgreek.sty'
Package `xgreek' version 2.0 by Apostolos Syropoulos
\@attic@num=\count98
) (./basic.aux)
\openout1 = `basic.aux'.
```

Comment: You have to load `amssymb` to be able to use `\subsetneq`

Comment: If you troll through the contents of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://goo.gl/NjJCc) you'll probably find that you need `amssymb`.

Comment: I don't get those errors at all. Did you load some package that is not in your example? Do you possibly have a corrupted version of amssymb.sty? Mine has file length 13829 bytes.

Comment: I have tried amssymb but I still get error messages. Regarding the size of amssymb.sty I have 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13613 Jun 30  2009 /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty

Comment: Does any of those packages define `\Game` or `\Finv` besides `amssymb`? Anyway you could try to open the style file and compy the `\DeclareMathSymbol` for the desired command into your preamble, as a last resort. I'll try compilig your code very soon.

Comment: What does that `no-math` option do?

Comment: Compiling your code as is gives me an `Undefined control sequence` error and no output, as should be expected without `amssymb`. Adding `amssymb` gets everything to work properly. I don't know why you are getting those errors. You probably have some corruption in some package or (even worse!) in the tex program itself. See what happens if you add `\DeclareMathSymbol{\subsetneq}{\mathrel}{AMSb}{"28}` to your preamble.

Comment: The font `AMSb` is not defined though. You will need `\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}` as well, _before_ the `\DeclareMathSymbol` above. Or you can load `amsfonts`.

Comment: Side note: according to my documentation, `cm-default` is an obsolete option, so you should be getting a warning about that since you are using it. Only you _aren't_. Which suggests you may have an outdated version at least of `fontspec`.